# nested while loops whith comments under eachother

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop, nested

I want to get each comment under the post. How do I nest the while loops correctly?

my result now is like this.

```
*Johannes: Johannes post nummer 1 2014-05-14 16:57:58 27

Victoria comments johannes post<br/>
Johannes comments Victorias post<br/>
Micke comments Mickes post<br/>
Christer comments Mickes post<br/>
```

But I want it like this:

```
*Johannes: Johannes post nummer 1 2014-05-14 16:57:58 27<br/>
Victoria comments johannes post

*Victoria: Victorias post nummer 1 2014-05-14 16:57:58 28<br/>
Johannes comments Victorias post
```

My code looks like this:

```
$commentsql = "SELECT comment,comment_post, post, post_id<br/>
               FROM comments,posts<br/>
               WHERE comment_post = post_id";<br/>

$result_sql = mysql_query($commentsql);<br/>
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $commentid = $row['post_id'];
    echo '<li>' .$row['username'] .': ' . $row['post'] . '  ' . $row['date'] . ' ' .          $row['post_id'] . '</li>' . '<br/>';

    while($comment = mysql_fetch_array($result_sql)) {
        echo $comment['comment'] . '<br/>' ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use 2 separate queries to achieve this result (or some right join magic as advanced option):

```
$post_resource = mysql_query("SELECT post_id, post FROM posts");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($post_resource)) {
   echo $row['post'] . "\n";
   $comments_resource = mysql_query("SELECT comment FROM comments WHERE comment_post=$row[post_id]");
   while($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($comment_resource)) {
      echo $comment['comment'] ."\n";
   }
   echo "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: There´s something wrong, it echo´s out each comment 4 times because there´s 4 comments stored in my database. how do i the echo it out just one time?

Comment: im wrong, its not because of the comments its something else.